# Azure DataFactory Run Activity in response to any one of several activities failing

Tags: azure-data-factory

Suppose I do a "setup" task part way through my pipeline, and then a matching cleanup task at the end.
If something goes wrong in-between I want to do a different cleanup task.

How do I configure that?

I can't just declare an on-failure dependency on the final task, since failures earlier in the chain mean that latter activities aren't run, and thus neither succeed NOR fail.

I can't see anyway to configure an "OR" dependency, like I would have back in the days of Sql Server Maintenance tasks :)

At the moment it seems like my best option is to copy my failure activity 5 times and each on to the failure of EACH intermediary step?

Comment: essentially I want to define a `try{}finally{}` block around a subset of my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the "Skipped" state.

Declare the 'failure cleanup' as happening if the setup Succeeded, and the 'success cleanup' was Skipped.

From MSDN on [Activity Dependency States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#activity-dependency):

> **Activity dependency**
>
> Activity Dependency defines how subsequent activities depend on previous activities, determining the condition of whether to continue executing the next task. An activity can depend on one or multiple previous activities with different dependency conditions.
>
> The different dependency conditions are: Succeeded, Failed, Skipped, Completed.
>
> For example, if a pipeline has Activity A -> Activity B, the different scenarios that can happen are:
>
> - Activity B has dependency condition on Activity A with *succeeded*:
>
>   - Activity B only runs if Activity A has a final status of *succeeded*.
> - Activity B has dependency condition on Activity A with *failed*:
>
>   - Activity B only runs if Activity A has a final status of *failed*.
> - Activity B has dependency condition on Activity A with *completed*:
>
>   - Activity B runs if Activity A has a final status of *succeeded* or *failed*
> - Activity B has a dependency condition on Activity A with *skipped*:
>
>   - Activity B runs if Activity A has a final status of *skipped*.
>   - *Skipped* occurs in the scenario of Activity X -> Activity Y -> Activity Z, where each activity runs only if the previous activity *succeeds*. If Activity X *fails*, then Activity Y has a status of *Skipped* because it never executes. Similarly, Activity Z has a status of *Skipped* as well.